# getting 2 div's next to each other and centering

Tags: css

I got 2 divs next to each other as follows:

```
#container{
    text-align: center;
}
#div1, #div2{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
}
```

`div1` has a form, the problem is that the elements in the form got distorted after I applied style for the `#container`. The elements were previously aligned as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/21/). But now they are [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/22/).

How do I get the elements aligned as they were before?

Comment: `How do I get the elements aligned as they were before?` => rollback to previous css... :)

Comment: @NoobEditor It's the same, but he changed his container's size.

Comment: @NoobEditor The previous CSS did not have `#container{text-align: center; }`. Thats the one creating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit your input elements to 50% as well, and instead of `display: inline-block` (which produces whitespace between elements), work with `float: left`.

```
label{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
p input {
    width: 50%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
```

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/24/)

Comment: That works well for the `input` elements but what about the `select` element? I did `text-align: left;` but it did not work. Also, why should I work with `float: left` instead?

Comment: Just extend the second rule to `p input, p select`. Like I said, floating elements produce no implicit margin. If you'd use `display: inline-block`, they wouldn't remain on the same line if both have 50% width (50% + 50% + some space > 100%).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything inside a alabel and then  [**see if this suits your purpose**](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/28/)

```
form, #movies_booked {
    width: 45%; /* ammended*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
label {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;/* ammended*/
    float:left;/* added */
    word-break:break-all;
}
label > input, label > select, label > span {
    float:right; /* added */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The text-align:center in the body is affecting all elements, just use:

```
form p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

To realign your text in the form.

In your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46xF5/29/)

Comment: Those elements are not aligned anymore when the viewport becomes small; just try and resize the lower-left window inside JSFiddle.